# Stop already running workflow/job in GitHub Actions

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have setup CI using GitHub Actions. One of my workflows is triggered by `push` events but it (or a job of this workflow) should not run on multiple instances the same time.

Is there a possible to create a job that stops the other workflow(or job or not allowing the workflow/job run in parallel)?

I would prefer cancelling the "old" job instead of the need for the "new" job to finish until the "old" job finished.

Ideally, I also want to run a job at the end that finishes the "old" job.(~saves the unfinished status). This can(but it doesn't have to) run parallel with the "new" job.

[**Note**]
I want to cancel a job in another workflow, or the other workflow, not another job in the same workflow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Now you can use offical concurrency support for Github Actions(**but still in beta**)

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#concurrency

both workflow and job supported!

```yaml
concurrency: 
  group: ${{ github.head_ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true
```

Comment: FYI use `github.ref` instead of `github.head_ref` if you'd like to cancel based on PR instead of whole project.

Answer (score 2):

Since Github has opened the new workflows API, I created this [small script](https://gist.github.com/ktmud/a0a9673254524d01189a8a7000829357) to manually cancel all unfinished jobs in one command:

```
Example:

  # Set up
  export GITHUB_TOKEN=394ba3b48494ab8f930fbc93
  export GITHUB_REPOSITORY=apache/incubator-superset

  # Cancel previous jobs for a PR
  ./cancel_github_workflows.py 1042

  # Cancel previous jobs for a branch
  ./cancel_github_workflows.py my-branch

  # Cancel all jobs including the last ones, this is useful
  # when you have closed a PR or deleted a branch and want
  # to cancel all its jobs.
  ./cancel_github_workflows.py 1024 --include-last
```

Answer (score 2):

To stop all the running workflow just add this job

```
jobs:
  cancel:
    name: 'Cancel Other Workflow'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: styfle/cancel-workflow-action@0.9.0
        with:
          access_token: ${{ github.token }}
```

You can also cancel specfic workflow by adding

```
workflow_id:<workflow id or workflow name>
```

in **with:** section.

for more information about this action check
https://github.com/styfle/cancel-workflow-action#readme